# Matlab's viterbi algorithm implementation in vitdec() function

Tags: matlab, decoding, decoder, viterbi, forwarderrorcorrection

I'm working on convolutional coding and decoding. In MATLAB, I'm using vitdec() function for decoding. Results are fine and bit error rate is as expected but I want to dig deeper into this function and I was doing it well until I hit vit() function which is being called by vitdec() (code line 402 in vitdec(function Matlab)). I'm unable to find any help regarding this function on MathWorks or anywhere else so far.

I'm pasting that part of vitdec() MATLAB function which uses vit() function below.

```
% Call to vit.c
 code   = double(code);      % for proper numerical operation
 [varargout{1}, varargout{2}, varargout{3}, varargout{4}] ...
   = vit(code, k, n, trellis.numStates, outputs,    trellis.nextStates,...
   tblen, opmodeNum, dectypeNum, nsdec, puncErasMode,    puncVectorRow,...
   erasVector, initTableSet, initmetric, initstate, initinput);
   % Set output data type to logical if appropriate
   if outLog, varargout{1} = logical(varargout{1}); 
end
else

 [varargout{1}, varargout{2}, varargout{3}, varargout{4}] ...
   = vitdeccore(code, k, n, trellis.numStates, outputs,    trellis.nextStates,...
   tblen, opmodeNum, dectypeNum, nsdec, puncErasMode,    puncVectorRow,...
   erasVector, initTableSet, initmetric, initstate, initinput);
```

I know how viterbi algorithm works. I have implemented it in C-language whose results match with those of MATLAB's. I just want to see how is videc() calculating branch and path metrics, step-by-step. Any link/book reference is appreciated.

Comment: `which vit` on my computer says it is a `mexw64` file. That means the code was written in another language (perhaps C) an then compiled, probably for performance reasons. So the source code is not available to Matlab

Comment: is there any way we can have access to it?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry

Comment: http://fog.misty.com/perry/research/viterbi/isi/vit_C.c This looks relatable. Doesn't it? @LuisMendo

Comment: That looks like a C/Mex program written by a particular user, not the official one by Mathworks.